# How to evaluate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Gamma(f(x))$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, gamma-function

If my math is correct:

$$\Gamma(f(x))=\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{f(x)-1}dt$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Gamma(f(x))=\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-t}f^\prime (x)\textrm{ln}(t)t^{f(x)-1}dt$$

$$=f^\prime (x)\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\textrm{ln}(t)t^{f(x)-1}dt$$

But here I get stuck. The integral is tantalizingly close to the definition of $\Gamma(f(x))$, except for the $\textrm{ln}(t)$ term. I've tried integration by parts to resolve the integral but no luck so far.

I'm hoping to find a formula for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Gamma(f(x))$ that can be expressed from the terms: $\Gamma(f(x))$, $\Gamma^\prime(x)$, or $\Gamma(x)$ and therefore can be calculated in the `R` program I'm running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the chain rule for derivatives.
$$\partial_x\Gamma(f(x))=\Gamma^\prime(f(x))f^\prime(x).
$$
Now using the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) defined by $\psi(x)=\partial_x\log\Gamma(x)$ we easily derive  $\Gamma^\prime(x)=\Gamma(x)\psi(x)$; hence,
$$\partial_x\Gamma(f(x))=\Gamma(f(x))\psi(f(x))f^\prime(x).
$$

**Edit:**

Based on OPs comments we may also use this approach:

By the chain rule and definition of digamma
$$\partial_x\log\Gamma(f(x))=\psi(f(x))f^\prime(x).
$$
But it is also true that
$$\partial_x\log\Gamma(f(x))=\frac{\partial_x\Gamma(f(x))}{\Gamma(f(x))}.
$$
Combining these equalities and rearranging to solve for $\partial_x\Gamma(f(x))$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Using the chain rule again, if we want to find $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\textrm{ln}(\Gamma(f(x))$:$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\textrm{ln}(\Gamma(f(x))=\psi(f(x))=\frac{\Gamma^\prime(f(x))}{\Gamma(f(x))}=\frac{\psi(f(x))\Gamma(f(x))f^\prime(x)}{\Gamma(f(x))}=\psi(f(x))f^\prime(x)$, is that correct?

Comment: @RobertF Almost, we still need to use the chain rule: $\partial_x\log\Gamma(f(x))=\psi(f(x)) f^\prime(x)$. But, $\partial_x\log\Gamma(f(x))=(\partial_x\Gamma(f(x)))/\Gamma(f(x))$ and so the result follows.

Comment: Yes if I break it out as $t=\textrm{ln}(u)$, $u=\Gamma(v)$, $v=f(x)$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\textrm{ln}(\Gamma(f(x))=\frac{\partial t}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(f(x))}\cdot\Gamma^\prime(f(x))\cdot f^\prime(x)=\psi(f(x))\cdot f^\prime(x)$. I think that's right.